# laravel command not found in mac os catalina

Tags: laravel

I am using Mac OS Catalina and I have already installed composer and laravel successfully. However, when I want to create a new laravel project via the terminal, it says `zsh: command not found: laravel`. Is this an operating system related issue?

Consider me a newbie, I'm not too sure what I have done wrong. Does anyone know how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you install Laravel (as a specific project) or the Laravel Installer? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#installing-laravel

Comment: I installed laravel as an installer using `composer global require laravel/installer` command

Comment: It's okay. I solved it,  I had to place the export path to nano bash profile and it seemed to work after that. i'm not sure what is the purpose of that bash file?

Comment: I use this command:
```php composer.phar dump-autoload```

Answer (score 6):

This is likely due to not having Composer's `vendor/bin` directory in your path. You can add it to your path by running the code below.

*You need to find out where composer is installing the vendor binaries first. This is usually in `~/.composer/vendor/bin` or `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin`.*

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: It's okay. I solved it, I had to place the export path to nano bash profile and it seemed to work after that. i'm not sure what is the purpose of that bash file?

Comment: The `.bashrc` file is a file that's loaded when you open up a new terminal window. It contains several configurations. One of them is defining the global `PATH` variable. This variable essentialy contains all the paths the terminal will look for when you're trying to run an executable.

Comment: Then from what I read, there's plenty of file that does the same thing like .bashsrc, .zsh and .vim, and so on. What are the differences? Do you need them all?

Comment: `.zshrc` is by the `zsh` shell and `.bashrc` is used by `bash`. I'm guessing `.vim` is used for `vim`.

Comment: my terminal by default uses zsh shell but I can still access `.bashrc` shell to configure the changes. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. You can have multiple shells installed. But only one will be used as a default. You can change the default shell by using the `chsh` command.

Comment: On MacOS Ventura.. use `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc`